# How to speed up geographic entity lookup (reverse geocoding?)?

Tags: performance-tuning, geography, geodesy

I have a very large set of coordinates (40,000+) that I need to categorise in a hierarchy of geographic entities; region, country, administrative divisions, city. I only have the coordinates and no other information about them.  My current approach - included below - is far to slow. It also suffers from not being able to select the city of the coordinate.

With

```
locs =
 GeoPosition /@ Reverse /@ RandomPoint[#, 1] & /@ 
   DiscretizeGraphics /@
    EntityValue[Keys@Select[Normal@EntityValue[RandomEntity["City", 700], "HasPolygon", 
         "EntityAssociation"], Values[#] == True &],
     "Polygon"] // Flatten
```

as the points.  I have constructed the following.

```
ClearAll[geoEntityCode];
With[{
  geoCode = {
    With[{rgn = DeleteCases[Entity["GeographicRegion", "World"]]@
         EntityValue["GeographicRegion", "Entities"]},
      Pick[rgn, GeoWithinQ[rgn, #1]]] &
    ,
    With[{cntry = 
        Flatten@EntityValue[#2, {EntityProperty["GeographicRegion", 
            "Countries"]}]},
      Pick[cntry, GeoWithinQ[cntry, #1]]] &
    ,
    With[{ad1 = 
        EntityList@
         Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {EntityProperty[
             "AdministrativeDivision", "ParentRegion"] -> #2}]},
      Pick[ad1, GeoWithinQ[ad1, #1]]] &
    ,
    With[{ad2 = #2["Subdivisions"]},
      Pick[ad2, GeoWithinQ[ad2, #1]]] &
    ,
    With[{city = 
        EntityList@
         Entity["City", {EntityProperty["City", 
             "AdministrativeDivision"] -> #2}]},
      Pick[city, GeoWithinQ[city, #1]]] &
    }
  },
 geoEntityCode[pos_GeoPosition] :=
  Module[{res = ConstantArray[Missing[], 5]},
   res[[1]] = First@geoCode[[1]][pos];
   (res[[#]] =
       Check[
        First@geoCode[[#]][pos, res[[# - 1]]],
        Missing[$MessageList[[-1]]]
        ]
      ) & /@ Range[2, 5];
   res
   ]
 ]
```

Then

```
geoEntityCode@First@locs
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

completes but takes far too long and gives a few errors on finding the city.

The odd thing is that *Wolfram|Alpha* finds this information exceptionally fast.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How do I improve this `Entity` performance and have it return the city (or nearest city)?  Or should I just try and grab the information from `WolframAlpha`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can use [`GeoIdentify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoIdentify.html) for this.

The following took 40 seconds on 250 random locations (the timing is internet dependent of course).

```
(* locs defined from code OP provided *)
Length[locs]
```

> ```
> 250
> ```

```
spec = "GeographicRegion" | "AdministrativeDivision1" | "AdministrativeDivision2" | "Country" | "City";
AbsoluteTiming[
  ids = DeleteCases[GeoIdentify[spec, locs], Entity["GeographicRegion", "World"], {2}];
]
```

> ```
> {39.465, Null}
> ```

```
Column[{First[locs], First[ids]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Big fat +1!  I don't know how I missed this function. It just below `GeoWithinQ` so I should have seen it.  This most likely is the answer.  Will wait a bit for the accept just in case.

Comment: Ok, glad it gave you what you wanted!